# Spring 4 API Request Authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4 to create an API and I need to have authentication for the API requests.

Currently, I have created a HandlerInterceptorAdapter to pick out authentication related headers and perform some validation on those values.

If everything is OK, I set the SecurityContext to a custom implementation of Authentication then in the postHandle I set the authentication to null.

Everything works great, **except** I keep getting warnings in Tomcat7 about ThreadLocal variables not being removed when the application shuts down.

```
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6c3e4fdb]) and a value of type [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl] (value [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

I get that I may be doing this totally wrong, if so I would love some direction. :D

Here is my interceptor:

```
/**
 * Intercepts Requests to set the Authentication in the SecurityContext.
 * Sets the response to 401 - Unauthorized, if the header is missing
 */
@Component
public class AuthenticationHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private HandlerMediator mediator;

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationHandlerInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationHandlerInterceptor(HandlerMediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        String username = request.getHeader("authentication-username");
        String token = request.getHeader("authentication-token");

        // if the remote host is local, then override the authentication
        if (request.getRemoteHost().equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1") || request.getRemoteHost().equals("127.0.0.1")) {
            log.info("On localhost, overriding authentication with localhost");
            username = "TEST";
            token = "localhost:localhost";
        }

        if (username == null || username.trim().length() == 0) {
            failAuthentication(response, "Missing Authentication Username Header");
            return false;
        }

        if (token == null || token.trim().length() == 0 || !token.contains(":")) {
            failAuthentication(response, "Missing Authentication Token Header");
            return false;
        }

        String[] keys = token.split(":");
        String appName = keys[0];
        String apikey = keys[1];

        if (!appName.equals("localhost")) {
            // we are not under localhost so we have to authenticate the application calling us
            if (mediator.executeCommand(new AuthenticateApplicationCommand(appName, apikey)) == false) {
                failAuthentication(response, "Application Token failed authentication");
                return false;
            }
        }

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new ApiAuthentication(username, appName));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }

    private void failAuthentication(HttpServletResponse response, String message) throws Exception {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        out.println(message);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

How do I get rid of these warnings?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do authentication based on the content of HTTP headers, the framework foresees a defining custom authentication filter, plugged in the spring security chain via configuration similar to this (see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811385/spring-security-custom-filter-positioning)):

```
<security:http>
        ...

    <security:custom-filter ref="customAuthenticationFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" /> 

</security:http>
```

There in this filter it's possible to add code similar to this (see also `BasicAuthenticationFilter`):

```
try {
       ....

       SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);


 } catch (AuthenticationException failed) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
 }
```

Have a look at class `ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy`,it's there that the `SecurityContextImpl` instance is getting stored in a ThreadLocal and cleared.

You could try to call clearContext() in `AuthenticationHandlerInterceptor`, but it's probably better to use the hook the framework foresees as that should lead to less surprises similar to the one you reported.